# ros2 argument in lauch.py

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a launch file with ROS1 as below. I want to wirte it with ros2 launch.py. How to write it with ros2 ？

```
<launch>
    <arg name="camera_type_tel" default="astrapro" doc="camera type [astrapro, astra,d435]"/>
    <include file="$(find camera_driver_transfer)/launch/$(arg camera_type_tel).launch">
    </include>
</launch>
```

I want to run the  camer launch file with argument , not use the string(d435_launch.py). I wirte it as below:  but when I run it ,it is error! how can I do ?

```
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import (DeclareLaunchArgument, GroupAction,
                            IncludeLaunchDescription)
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration

def generate_launch_description():
    # Get the launch directory
    camera_driver_transfer_dir = get_package_share_directory('camera_driver_transfer')
    camera_type_tel = LaunchConfiguration('camera_type_tel')

    declare_camera_type_tel = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'camera_type_tel', 
        default_value='d435',
        choices=['d435', 'astra_pro'],
        description='camera type')        
    camera_type_launch = camera_type_tel+'_launch.py'
    # Specify the actions
    camera_group = GroupAction([
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(camera_driver_transfer_dir, 'launch',  camera_type_launch))) #this is error                
            #PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(camera_driver_transfer_dir, 'launch',  'd435_launch.py'))) #this is ok
    ])

    # Create the launch description and populate
    ld = LaunchDescription()
    ld.add_action(declare_camera_type_tel)
    ld.add_action(camera_group)

    return ld
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403236/ros2-argument-in-lauch.py/) by [drink](https://answers.ros.org/users/41674/drink/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-07-03**:
What type of error are you receiving? Please also add the information from the terminal. This line: `camera_type_launch = camera_type_tel+'_launch.py'` looks incorrect to me, where did you find such use of `DeclareLaunchArgument` as a string to concatenate? Are you sure it is a string? The later error may come from this.

**Comment by [drink](https://answers.ros.org/users/41674/drink/) on 2022-07-04**:
yes, you are right. I want to get the result of DeclareLaunchArgument as sting type.But it seens it has not. I don't know how to do it. Have you a good way to implement this feature on ROS2?

```
<launch>
    <arg name="camera_type_tel" default="astrapro" doc="camera type [astrapro, astra,d435]"/>
    <include file="$(find camera_driver_transfer)/launch/$(arg camera_type_tel).launch">
    </include>
</launch>
```

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-07-04**:
I think this question answers how you can get it as a string: https://answers.ros.org/question/396345/ros2-launch-file-how-to-convert-launchargument-to-string/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We need to always remember that launch works in 2 sort of steps: Describe and Execution. (See my response here: https://answers.ros.org/question/396345/ros2-launch-file-how-to-convert-launchargument-to-string/?answer=396630#post-id-396630)

But since you plan to use the substitution object as an argument to something that accepts substitutions, you can combine the strings and substitution as a tuple (Though you can't do things like os.path.join with substitutions). So changing to use

```
...
camera_type_launch = (camera_driver_transfer_dir, '/launch/', camera_type_tel, '_launch.py')
camera_group = GroupAction([
    IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(camera_type_launch))
])
```

should work just fine.

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2022-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drink](https://answers.ros.org/users/41674/drink/) on 2022-07-06**:
you are right. that is what I want.